# Why java.util.ArrayList.remove(int index) is not working properly for the below code?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I was trying to execute the below code. It ran without any compilation errors. But the `remove(int index)` method is not working as expected.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Stones {
    static int findLastStoneWeight(ArrayList<Integer> weight)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Collections.sort(weight);
            int n=weight.size();
            if (n==1)
                return weight.get(0);
            else if(weight.get(n-1)>weight.get(n-2))
            {
                int temp1=weight.get(n-1);
                int temp2=weight.get(n-2);
                weight.add(n-2,temp1-temp2);
                weight.remove(n-1);
                System.out.println(weight.size()); //The new size of weight should be decreased by 1 but it does not!!
            }
            else
            {
                weight.remove(n-1);
                weight.remove(n-2);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> weight=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter the weights:");
        while(true)
        {
            int w=sc.nextInt();
            if(w<0)
                break;
            weight.add(w);
        }
        int lswt=findLastStoneWeight(weight);
        System.out.println("Last stone weight:"+lswt);
    }
}
```

When I used the `remove(int index)` method on the `ArrayList weight` the size of the `ArrayList` should get reduced by 1 but it remains the same. Why?

Comment: try printing elements and see if indeed its changed or not after removing the element and before removing the element.

Comment: @SMA the elements of the ArrayList are getting changed but `remove(int index)` is not squeezing the `ArrayList`. I tried with the inputs `[1,2,3,-99]` the function `findLastStoneWeight(ArrayList<Integer>)` is also getting called but it's never returning as it got stuck in the loop. As the size of the `ArrayList` is not getting decreased the program is never terminating.

Comment: Your code will run in infinite loop as you don't have exit condition.Only exit condition is when n is 1. However if you give input with n > 1 it will never stop. I suppose you have to decrement value of n in else block.

Comment: @RishiSaraf the value of `n` should get automatically decreased as I am using the `remove(int index)` method on the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `else if` branch you noted, you first add an element to the `weight` ArrayList:

```
weight.add(n-2,temp1-temp2);
```

and then remove an element:

```
weight.remove(n-1);
```

All in all, you've added an element and removed an element, so the size of the list at the end of the method will be same as it was in the metho'd begining.

Comment: I added a new value in a position that already exists in the ArrayList. I have not used the `add(Integer)` method which adds an element at the end of the list.

Comment: @PratipChakraborty you've inserted an element somewhere in the list. All the elements in that position and above will be shifted (i.e., their index will be incremented by one). See the [method's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-) for additional details.

Comment: @PratipChakraborty if you need to replace element you need to use `set(index, element)` instead

Comment: I got your point that `add(int index, Integer value)` will just insert that `value` in the specified `index` but will not update the same. Thank you @Mureinik & @Ivan.